# How to: Format a MySQL query result with currency signs using PHP

Tags: mysql, css, formatting, currency, number-formatting

I have a MySQL query that fetches a numeric value `VARCHAR (20)` from a table, and I need to format the result to include thousands separators (`,`) and decimal separators (`.`) to two positions.

I've searched a lot for a simple query, so now I want to know if this is possible using CSS.

Here is the table data:

```
Income
-------------------
1234456789
234456000
987456000
```

And so on. Here's the query:

```
// Fetch data

$sql="SELECT * FROM scoreboard WHERE codcliente = '".$q."' OR nombre LIKE '%".$q."%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
  echo '<div align="center" style="background-color:#CCCCCC; font-weight:bold; color:#C0504D;">Record no existe.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="srchcreate" type="button" value="Crear" /></div>';
  return;
  }
//echo $result;
```

And the result:

```
// Construct the table

echo "<table>";

// Construct the array

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['codcliente'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nombre'] . "</td>";
//  echo "<td>" . $row['ejecutivo'] . "</td>";
//  echo "<td>" . $row['banca_as400'] . "</td>";
//  echo "<td>" . $row['banca_real'] . "</td>";
//  echo "<td>" . $row['ingresos'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ciiu'] . "</td>";
//  echo "<td>" . $row['division'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['actividad'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['riesgo_industria'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['riesgo_cliente'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['fecha'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['analista'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This gets inserted to a PHP file and displayed as a table.

Comment: You don't want to style/format the query. You want to format the output. You need to tell us what language you use to pass queries to database and the results to the browser. Preferably paste some code example.

Comment: css can style things, not change the actual content.

Comment: Thanks guys, but that's what I meant, format the result not the query, my question is worded like that. I will update the question title and paste some code. I'm working with PHP/MySQL/AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
echo number_format(123456789, 2);
?>
```

`123,456,789.00`

```
echo "<td>".number_format($row['ingresos'], 2)."</td>\n"
```

Comment: Thanks, I had looked into that, but I can't use it because the result is constructed dynamically. If you can tell me how to add it to an `echo "<td>{$row['ingresos']}</td>\n"`, then we're in business.

Comment: @rdrgrtz, well dynamic is the point of PHP, see updated answer ;)

Comment: Awesome @webarto! Any way to put a ($) in front? Or am I pushing it?

Comment: @rdrgrtz, Just change first `"<td>"` to `"<td>($)"` :)

Comment: Works, but instead of `"<td>($)"` it works better with `"<td>$nbsp;"` @webarto

Answer (score 3):

No, CSS isn't designed to do that.

JavaScript does have that capability.